# KendoUI Sortable not working in 2014.3.1119 release

Tags: kendo-ui

I have following JS fiddles with same piece of code for kendui's sortable connected lists. One works and other doesn't in latest release of the kendoui.

2014.2.903 Working Version -> http://jsfiddle.net/m72f5z6h/3/ 
2014.3.1119 Non Working Version -> http://jsfiddle.net/m72f5z6h/2/

JS Code for creating the sortable lists:

```
$(function(){
var panelHeaders = $(".panel-header");

panelHeaders.click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var thisContent = $(this).next(".panel-content");
    if(thisContent.is(":visible"))
        thisContent.slideUp();
    else
        thisContent.slideDown();
});

var panels1 = ".panel-column-1";
var panels2 = ".panel-column-2";

function sortablePlaceholder(element) {
    return element.clone()
    .css({ "opacity": 0.8, });
}
function sortableHint(element) {
    return element.clone()
    .css({ "border": "1px solid #a2a2a2" })
    .height(element.height())
    .width(element.width());
}

// Sortable
$(panels1).kendoSortable({
    cursor: "move",
    connectWith: panels2,
    placeholder: sortablePlaceholder,
    hint: sortableHint
});

$(panels2).kendoSortable({
    cursor: "move",
    connectWith: panels1,
    placeholder: sortablePlaceholder,
    hint: sortableHint
});
```

});

You can't drag/ drop the panels in the latest release for kendoui (2014.3.1119)  for the same piece of code.

Anybody have idea if API got changed? I tried to look at the samples and it looks same.

Any help is appreciated...

Update: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/sortable/linkedlists also shows the same behaviour...

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are facing this:

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/430

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the same issue. Also it also occurs at IE11/ Windows 8.

Comment: Just merged the code locally from https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/430 and it works now. Thanks @Pyeto